# Why are sometimes not all NSDocument windows opened?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsdocument

I am writing an NSDocument based app. Currently, I am calling `AppKit > NSDocument > func addWindowController(_ windowController: NSWindowController)` multiple times to open multiple windows per NSDocument.

```
override func makeWindowControllers() {
    let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: NSStoryboard.Name("Main"), bundle: nil)
    let sceneidentifier : [String] = [ "si1", "si2" ]

    for x in 0..<sceneidentifier.count {
        let wc = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.sceneidentifier("WindowController")) as! NSWindowController
        wc.contentViewController = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.sceneidentifier(sceneidentifier[x])) as? NSViewController
        self.addWindowController(wc)
    }
}
```

As a result of this code, multiple windows should be shown per NSDocument but sometimes, randomly only one window appears when running.

Comment: "Sometimes" and "randomly" may have to do with state restoration and the window's Visible at Launch option. If you always want them visible, have you called makeKeyAndOrderFront on each window explicitly in showWindows()?

Comment: @seth No. I just implemented that and it seems to work, although it is hard to confirm due to the problem only appearing sometimes. But I just discovered that if I write in the NSTextView of the window normally appearing second, quit the app and run it again, the window I just wrote in appears first and is in front of the other window.